Can I put Tefilen back on
If I took off my Tefilen and realized that I forgot to say the 2 paragraphs that one must say with tifilen on should I put them back on if so should I make a bracha.
Thanks to all that help

The MB in 25:16 mentions the idea to say these parshiyos, and says it’s a nice minhag.(So it is definitely not required to put back on your tefillin for that):

(טז) להניח ד' פרשיות - ויש נוהגים מחמת זה לקרות הארבע פרשיות לאחר הנחת תפלין היינו קדש והיה כי יביאך דשמע והיה אם שמוע בלא"ה קורין כל ישראל בשעת ק"ש. ובתפלין דר"ת יאמר כל הד' פרשיות. ומנהג יפה הוא [ארה"ח]:


Because of this, there are those who have the custom of reading the four passages after putting on their tefillin.  Meaning, [only] - (Exodus 13:1) "Sanctify [to Me all the first-born]...", (Exodus 13:11) "It shall be, when Hashem brings you [to the land]...", because "Shema" and "Vehaya im shamoa", even if you don't read it here, everyone reads it [later] during recitation of Shema.  And [after putting on] Rabbeinu Tam tefillin, one should recite all four passages.  And this is a nice custom [Artzos Hachaim]....

Having said that, if you do choose to put them back on to say these parshiyos, you would have to make another bracha. The reason for that is because when you removed them you didn’t have in mind to put them back on. This is mentioned in MB 25:47

ואם לא היה בדעתו להחזירו מיד רק לאחר זמן אפילו אם אח"כ לבשן תיכף או שהיה בדעתו להחזירן תיכף ואח"כ נשתהא הדבר והסיח דעתו בינתים לכו"ע צריך לחזור ולברך


If one didn't intend to put them back on immediately, but rather after some time - even if he ended up putting them back on right away; Or if one intended to put them back on immediately, but then it got delayed and he got distracted - All agree that he must recite the blessing again

As an aside, I once heard in a shiur that R’ Belsky told a talmid once, to put back on his tefillin with a bracha to say these parshiyos, when he mentioned to him that he forgot to say them.
